# What is the purpose of export interface Props in React (Typescript ver)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the *Creating a component* section of [React Typescript Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter#typescript-react-starter) example, Creating a component, there is a basic React component in Typescript:

```
// src/components/Hello.tsx

import * as React from 'react';

export interface Props {
  name: string;
  enthusiasmLevel?: number;
}

function Hello({ name, enthusiasmLevel = 1 }: Props) {
  if (enthusiasmLevel <= 0) {
    throw new Error('You could be a little more enthusiastic. :D');
  }

  return (
    <div className="hello">
      <div className="greeting">
        Hello {name + getExclamationMarks(enthusiasmLevel)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hello;

// helpers

function getExclamationMarks(numChars: number) {
  return Array(numChars + 1).join('!');
}
```

I am new to Typescript. It seems that the interface Props is used by Typescript to do props type checks (similar to what the [Proptypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) npm package does). So the question is:

1. If I am already using this kind of Typescript
   interface syntax do to props type check, do I still need to use
   Proptypes package like this in the same component?

```
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    Hello.propTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.string,
      enthusiasmLevel: PropTypes.number
    };
```

2. Besides, why does here use **export** interface? what is the purpose
   of exporting the interface Props? Is it compulsory?

Comment: exporting so you can import your props contract when using the component from other components. If you were to use your Hello component you would like to know which props it takes.

Comment: Just an update from myself after using TS for a year: `export interface Props` because the Props interface is also usually used in unit text files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly I recommend declaring your components the ES6 way

```
const Hello: React.FC<IHello> = ({ name, enthusiasmLevel = 1 }) => {}
```

Your interface defines the contract of your component / The accepted parameters

```
export interface IHello {
  name: string;
  enthusiasmLevel?: number;
}
```

You are exporting this, so you can import your interface from other files / components which want to make use of the `Hello` component. For example you can use your `Hello` component like so from another component:

```
const props: IHello = {
    name: "John",
    enthusiamsLevel: 5
}

<Hello {...props} />
```

> If I am already using this kind of Typescript interface syntax do to props type check, do I still need to use Proptypes in the same component?

You always want type strong definitions in TypeScript. So when declaring your prop variable in another component, you don't want to do `const props: any = {`
If you decide to change your interface declaration for this component later on, you would be forced to update all your references which uses this interface. - You might want to require 1 more prop variable and in that case you would want to update your usages of this interface. If you are not used to TypeScript this can seem quite hideous at first - but the benefit of always having strong type definitions will show over time. Especially when you update your type definitions.

Comment: Thanks, Jonas! To illustrate the point again, if I need to use the `<Hello />` component elsewhere, I could use `props.name: string` to type-check the props variables in that component (like <HelloParent />). That is why I need to export it in Hello, and I also need to import the interface like `import Hello, { IHello } from './Hello'` in `<HelloParent />`?

Comment: The `IHello` interface is used for props type-checking in `<Hello />` component itself. If I do not use the component at other places, I do not need to export it. But if I export the interface, it could also be used along with the component elsewhere (which may be the usual cases), which seems to enforce the type-checking everywhere?

Comment: Yes, you can create an object of type `IHello` and simply pass it to the `Hello` component. There is a lot of tricks and implementations that can really benefit from this. Imagine the `HelloParent` component uses the `Hello` component and `FooBar` component - you could declare the type of `HelloParent` as `const HelloParent: React.FC<IHello & IFooBar>` which merges the 2 interfaces into 1. But that is just an example, you could also merge with your redux container types.

Comment: Thanks. Besides, do I also need to use the PropTypes npm package for type-checking which was used in normal React Javascript projects?

Comment: Why is component declaring recommended the ES6 way? What are the advantages?

Comment: @user1563544 Several advantages: 
Arrow syntax automatically binds this to the surrounding code’s context
The syntax allows an implicit return when there is no body block, resulting in shorter and simpler code in some cases
Last but not least, => is shorter and simpler than function, although stylistic issues are often subjective source: https://codeutopia.net/blog/2015/01/06/es6-what-are-the-benefits-of-the-new-features-in-practice/

Comment: why do you recommend creating components in ES6 way?